# Das ist mir egal vs. Das ist für mich egal

Tags: meaning

I know the first one (`Das ist mir ...`) is the standard one, but is the second one (`Das ist für mich ...`) correct?

`egal` is just an example to demonstrate my question. Another word can be used like "klar": `Das ist für mich klar.`

I know `mir` and `für mich` cannot be used interchangeably in many cases, please focus on these two sentences.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/f%c3%bcr-mich-vs-mir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Für mich VS. mir](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/f%c3%bcr-mich-vs-mir)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use it, although I think it's more common to use it in this order:

> A: Wenn wir zum Europapark wollen, müssen wir aber früh aufstehen!
> B: **Für mich ist das egal**, aber C ist definitiv kein Frühaufsteher!
>
> A: If we wanted to go to the Europapark tomorrow, we'd have to get up early
> B: I don't mind, but C is no morning person.

That way you emphasize that it doesn't matter for **you**.

Comment: Saying "Mir ist das egal" doesn't emphasize "me" already ?

Comment: It does emphasize the "me" as much as "I don't care" emphasizes the "I". The version with "für mich" more or less requires the contrast that it might matter for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

*Für mich ist das egal* is grammatically correct, but in my view, besides from being somewhat unusual, it is less clear than *Mir ist das egal*.

*Mir ist das egal* means *I don't care [about this]*. *Für mich ist das egal* could mean the same but it could also be meant more objectively. A better translation would then be something like *This doesn't matter as far as I am concerned*. It could also mean *In my opinion this doesn't matter*.

Answer (score -1):

An den Beispielen von @infinitezero wird der Unterschied recht deutlich

> A: Wenn wir zum Europapark wollen, müssen wir aber früh aufstehen!
>   B: **Für mich ist das egal**, aber C ist definitiv kein Frühaufsteher!

Ich hätte zwar erst vermutet, dass *für mich* mit bestimmten Prädikaten gar nicht vorkommt. Tatsächlich kommt es nicht in der Bedeutung vor, die bei *mir ist das egal* vordergründig ist, wie @ IZ treffend auf den Punkt brachte.

Denn wenn *mir das egal ist* und *das* hier auf *wir müssen früh aufstehen* bezogen ist, wäre die *aber*-Klause ein Widerspruch. Gut, es kommt vor, dass sich einer Widerspricht, und das mag auch ein valides Stilmittel der Alltagssprache sein. Aber die Phrase *für mich* stellt halt heraus, dass das *frühe Aufstehen* in Bezug genommen wird, jedoch mit einem anderen Subjekt.

Oder kurz gesagt, ob das Aufstehen für ihn aus meiner Sicht nicht egal ist, bedeutet noch lange nicht, dass es ihm selbst nicht doch egal wäre, sowie es ihm eventuel egal sein kann, ob es mir nicht egal ist, ob es ihm egal wäre, etc. etc. Hat also potential zu einer Höflichkeitsform, die eine gewisse Objektivität wahrt, mir allerdings nicht wirklich förmlich erscheint.

Comment: The OP speaks English.